# PHP spell checking tool

Tags: php, spell-checking

Is there such a tool that finds language/spelling errors in code comment and strings in PHP code? for example,

```
<?php
$myVar = "Hollo World";
//this is a code commont with spelling error
/*this is anothor wrong comment*/
?>
```

If I run such a tool, then it will find 'Hollo', 'commont', and 'anothor' spelling errors for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDEs such as Eclipse or NetBeans would do the spell checking themselves, you need only to enable such features.

Comment: +1 for NetBeans. [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) for Mac also spell checks comments and string literals.

Comment: Where to enable it in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at the [**PHP**](http://php.net/) function **[pspell_check()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php)** which is part of **[Pspell](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php)**.

It requires the **[Aspell library](http://aspell.sourceforge.net/)**.

You might also be interested in **[Enchant](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.enchant.php)**, the PHP binding for the **[Enchant Library](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/)**. It supports Aspell, and in the words of the documentation:

> Enchant steps in to provide uniformity and conformity on top of all spelling libraries, and implement certain features that may be lacking in any individual provider library.

---

Here's a `pspell_check()` example from the documentation. First you link to the appropriate dictionary, then you perform the spell check:

```
<?php
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");

if (pspell_check($pspell_link, "testt")) 
{
    echo "This is a valid spelling";
} else 
{
    echo "Sorry, wrong spelling";
}
?>

// Output is "Sorry, wrong spelling"
```

To check spelling in an entire file (like all code and comments in a program), you could transform the file to a string using **[`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)**, strip punctuation with **[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**, break it into words with **[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**, and run it through the spell check.

---

Since your question is tagged `PHP`, I assume you would like a `PHP` oriented programmatic solution; however, there are, of course, myriads of spell check options outside of PHP as well.