# Spell check and suggest proper word in PHP

Tags: php, spell-checking

I was wondering if anyone knows of any library, script, or service that can spell check a string and return a suggestion of the properly spelled word or suggestions if more that one properly spelled word that it could be written in PHP.

I would prefer if there wasn't a limit on the amount of queries I could do, so not like Google's APIs.

It would be great if it could function like this:

```
// string to be spell checked stored in variable
$misspelledString = "The quick brown lama jumped over the lazy dog.";

//pass that variable to function

//function returns suggestion or suggestions as an array of string or strings

$suggestion = spellCheck($misspelledString);

echo "Did you mean ".$suggestion[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the included Pspell functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pspell.php

Or an external plugin, like this one:

http://www.phpspellcheck.com/

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688723/php-spell-checking-tool) for an example.

Comment: I have PHP 5.3 on my server and PSpell is not a part of that release or any after.

Comment: @Filippos is there any example for getting input from input, checking the spelling, and displaying corrected suggestions on a search result page without a modal or popup window?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as nice an API as in your example, but Pspell would be an option. It may already be included with your system copy of PHP. You'll need aspell libraries for each language you want to check.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php

On my debian based machine, it's included in the system repositories as a separate package, php5-pspell.

Comment: I have PHP 5.3 on my machine and the manual says PSpell is no longer part of PHP.

Comment: Are you able to install packages on your server or is it hosted?

Comment: It is hosted, I don't think I am allowed to install any packages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "pspell" PHP extension, you can install it on Linux using CLI:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pspell;
sudo service apache2 restart;
```

The code is very simple:

```
if ($word = $_GET['word']) {
    $spellLink = pspell_new("en");

    if (!pspell_check($spellLink, $word)) {
        $suggestions = pspell_suggest($spellLink, $word);
        echo '<p>Did you mean: <i>"'.$suggestions[0].'"</i>?</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to create a class that takes a list of phrases and compares that to the user inputs.  What I was trying to do is get things like Porshre Ceyman  to correct to Porsche Cayman for example.

This class requires an array of correct terms $this->full_model_list , and an array of the user input $search_terms. I took out the contruct so you will need to pass in the  full_model_list. Note, this didn't fully work so I decided to scrap it, it was adapted from someone looking to correct large sentences ...

You would call it like so:

```
$sth = new SearchTermHelper;
$resArr = $sth->spellCheckModelKeywords($search_terms)
```

Code (VERY BETA) :

```
<?php

/*
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// FUNCTION: Search Term Helper Class
// PURPOSE: Handles finding matches and such with search terms for keyword searching.
// DETAILS: Functions below build search combinations, find matches, look for spelling issues in words etc.
//
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

class SearchTermHelper
{
    public $full_model_list;
    private $inv;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- return an array of metaphones for each word in a string
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private function getMetaPhone($phrase)
    {
        $metaphones = array();
        $words = str_word_count($phrase, 1);
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $metaphones[] = metaphone($word);
        }
        return $metaphones;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- return the closest matching string found in $this->searchAgainst when compared to $this->input
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function findBestMatchReturnString($searchAgainst, $input, $max_tolerance = 200, $max_length_diff = 200, $min_str = 3, $lower_case = true, $search_in_phrases = true)
    {
        if (empty($searchAgainst) || empty($input)) return "";

        //weed out strings we thing are too small for this
        if (strlen($input) <= $min_str) return $input;

        $foundbestmatch = -1;
        if ($lower_case) $input = strtolower($input);

        //sort list or else not best matches may be found first
        $counts = array();
        foreach ($searchAgainst as $s) {
            $counts[] = strlen($s);
        }
        array_multisort($counts, $searchAgainst);

        //get the metaphone equivalent for the input phrase
        $tempInput = implode(" ", $this->getMetaPhone($input));
        $list = array();

        foreach ($searchAgainst as $phrase) {

            if ($lower_case) $phrase = strtolower($phrase);

            if ($search_in_phrases) $phraseArr = explode(" ",$phrase);

            foreach ($phraseArr as $word) {
                //get the metaphone equivalent for each phrase we're searching against
                $tempSearchAgainst = implode(' ', $this->getMetaPhone($word));
                $similarity = levenshtein($tempInput, $tempSearchAgainst);

                if ($similarity == 0) // we found an exact match
                {
                    $closest = $word;
                    $foundbestmatch = 0;
                    echo "" . $closest . "(" . $foundbestmatch . ") <br>";
                    break;
                }

                if ($similarity <= $foundbestmatch || $foundbestmatch < 0) {
                    $closest = $word;
                    $foundbestmatch = $similarity;

                    //keep score
                    if (array_key_exists($closest, $list)) {
                        //echo "" . $closest . "(" . $foundbestmatch . ") <br>";

                        $list[$closest] += 1;
                    } else {
                        $list[$closest] = 1;
                    }

                }
            }

            if ($similarity == 0 || $similarity <= $max_tolerance) break;
        }

        // if we find a bunch of a value, assume it to be what we wanted
        if (!empty($list)) {
            if ($most_occuring = array_keys($list, max($list)) && max($list) > 10) {
                return $closest;
            }
        }

        //echo "input:".$input."(".$foundbestmatch.")  match: ".$closest."\n";

        // disallow results to be all that much different in char length (if you want)
        if (abs(strlen($closest) - strlen($input)) > $max_length_diff) return "";


        // based on tolerance of difference, return if match meets this requirement (0 = exact only 1 = close, 20+ = far)
        return ((int)$foundbestmatch <= (int)$max_tolerance) ? $closest : "";
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Handles passing arrays instead of a string above ( could have done this in the func above )
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function findBestMatchReturnArray($searchAgainst, $inputArray, $max_tolerance = 200, $max_length_diff = 200, $min_str = 3)
    {
        $results = array();
        $tempStr = '';
        foreach ($inputArray as $item) {
            if ($tmpStr = $this->findBestMatchReturnString($searchAgainst, $item, $max_tolerance, $max_length_diff, $min_str))
                $results[] = $tmpStr;
        }
        return (!empty($results)) ? $results : $results = array();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Build combos of search terms -- So we can check Cayman S or S Cayman etc.
    //    careful, this is very labor intensive ( O(n^k) )
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function buildSearchCombinations(&$set, &$results)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($set); $i++) {

            $results[] = $set[$i];
            $tempset = $set;
            array_splice($tempset, $i, 1);
            $tempresults = array();
            $this->buildSearchCombinations($tempset, $tempresults);

            foreach ($tempresults as $res) {
                $results[] = trim($set[$i]) . " " . trim($res);
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Model match function -- Get best model match from user input.
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function findBestSearchMatches($model_type, $search_terms, $models_list)
    {

        $partial_search_phrases = array();
        if (count($search_terms) > 1) {
            $this->buildSearchCombinations($search_terms, $partial_search_phrases);     // careful, this is very labor intensive ( O(n^k) )
            $partial_search_phrases = array_diff($partial_search_phrases, $search_terms);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($search_terms); $i++) $partial_search_phrases[] = $search_terms[$i];
            $partial_search_phrases = array_values($partial_search_phrases);
        } else {
            $partial_search_phrases = $search_terms;
        }

        //sort list or else not best matches may be found first
        $counts = array();
        foreach ($models_list as $m) {
            $counts[] = strlen($m);
        }
        array_multisort($counts,SORT_DESC,$models_list);
        unset($counts);

        //sort list or else not best matches may be found first
        foreach ($partial_search_phrases as $p) {
            $counts[] = strlen($p);
        }
        array_multisort($counts,SORT_DESC,$partial_search_phrases);

        $results = array("exact_match" => '', "partial_match" => '');
        foreach ($partial_search_phrases as $term) {
            foreach ($models_list as $model) {
                foreach ($model_type as $mt) {

                    if (strpos(strtolower($model), strtolower($mt)) !== false) {
                        if ((strtolower($model) == strtolower($term) || strtolower($model) == strtolower($mt . " " . $term))
                        ) {
                           // echo " " . $model . "  ===  " . $term . " <br>";

                            if (strlen($model) > strlen($results['exact_match']) /*|| strtolower($term) != strtolower($mt)*/
                            ) {
                                $results['exact_match'] = strtolower($model);
                                return $results;
                            }
                        } else if (strpos(strtolower($model), strtolower($term)) !== false) {

                            if (strlen($term) > strlen($results['partial_match'])
                                || strtolower($term) != strtolower($mt)
                            ) {
                                $results['partial_match'] = $term;
                                //return $results;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Get all models in DB for Make (e.g. porsche) (could include multiple makes)
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function initializeFullModelList($make) {
        $this->full_model_list = array();
        $modelsDB = $this->inv->getAllModelsForMakeAndCounts($make);
        foreach ($modelsDB as $m) {
            $this->full_model_list[] = $m['model'];
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- spell checker -- use algorithm to check model spelling (could expand to include english words)
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function spellCheckModelKeywords($search_terms)
    {
        // INPUTS:  findBestMatchReturnArray($searchList, $inputArray,$tolerance,$differenceLenTolerance,$ignoreStringsOfLengthX,$useLowerCase);
        //
        // $searchList,  - The list of items you want to get a match from
        // $inputArray,  - The user input value or value array
        // $tolerance,   - How close do we want the match to be 0 = exact, 1 = close, 2 = less close, etc. 20 = find a match 100% of the time
        // $lenTolerance, - the number of characters between input and match allowed, ie. 3 would mean match can be +- 3 in length diff
        // $ignoreStrLessEq, - min number of chars that must be before checking (i.e. if 3 ignore anything 3 in length to check)
        // $useLowerCase - puts the phrases in lower case for easier matching ( not needed per se )
        // $searchInPhrases - compare against every word in searchList (which could be groups of words per array item (so search every word past to function

        $tolerance = 0;     // 1-2 recommended
        $lenTolerance = 1; // 1-3 recommended
        $ignoreStrLessEq = 3; // may not want to correct tiny words, 3-4 recommended
        $useLowercase = true; // convert to lowercase matching = true
        $searchInPhrases = true; //match words not phrases, true recommended

        $spell_checked_search_terms = $this->findBestMatchReturnArray($this->full_model_list, $search_terms, $tolerance, $lenTolerance, $ignoreStrLessEq, $useLowercase,$searchInPhrases);
        $spell_checked_search_terms = array_values($spell_checked_search_terms);

        // return spell checked terms
        if (!empty($spell_checked_search_terms)) {
            if (strpos(strtolower(implode(" ", $spell_checked_search_terms)), strtolower(implode(" ", $search_terms))) === false //&&
              //  strlen(implode(" ", $spell_checked_search_terms)) > 4
            ) {
                return $spell_checked_search_terms;
            }
        }

        // or just return search terms as is
        return $search_terms;
    }

}

?>
```