# How to recognize compound words in a text and figure out if it's make sense with PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing an application for getting the keywords in php from the text then search for compound keywords for example if I have:

```
Coffee Digital Marketing Sports car
```

so I want to figure out some compound words like Digital Marketing and Sports car and know if it's compound or not and if it's make sense to find suggestion based on this word
the problem is how to figure out if it's make sense I can get a pair of previous words but how to know if they correctly compounded

Comment: Yes it makes sense with PHP, but depends on the logic used.

Comment: I Just wan to get the multiple topics from the text the user provides, I mean the word itself makes sense for example if make suggestion on Digital only that won't make sense for the topic because it's digital marketing topic or if I got only sports and the user means sports car etc..

Comment: So I want to make a pair of each two words for example Coffee Digital then Digital Marketing but how to know if Coffee Digital it's not the right compound

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3688913/984422

Comment: I figured out it's not about spelling, It's should be something like compound English Dictionary words and we compound each word then search in the dictionary if the word exists

Comment: Something exactly like that but in English
https://github.com/paslandau/dictionary-decompounder